# Update object with extra attribute using ngModel

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-forms

I have an object which I am rendering to table (inline-edit) with ngModel & there are some cases when any particular value will not be available, below is the example:

```
[{
    results: [
        {
            name: 'abc',
            phone1: '98888',
            phone2: '988883'
        },
        {
            name: 'xyz',
            phone1: '98888'
        }
    ]
}]

<tr *ngFor="let contact of results">
    <td><input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="contact.name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="phone1" [(ngModel)]="contact.phone1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="phone2" [(ngModel)]="contact.phone2"></td>
</tr>
```

Since in the second object phone2 is not present it gives an error so how I can handle it & since its an inline-edit table, I want to add that phone2 if user enters it. How I can achieve this?

Update:
If property is not present getting this error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./Spreadsheet class Spreadsheet - inline template:83:85
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at DebugAppView._View_Spreadsheet6.detectChangesInternal (Spreadsheet.template.js:1233)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:234)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:339)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectContentChildrenChanges (view.js:252)
    at DebugAppView._View_Spreadsheet0.detectChangesInternal (Spreadsheet.template.js:557)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:234)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:339)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (view.js:260)
    at DebugAppView._View_Spreadsheet_Host0.detectChangesInternal (Spreadsheet_Host.template.js:36)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:234)
    ERROR CONTEXT:
DebugContext {_view: _View_Spreadsheet6, _nodeIndex: 53, _tplRow: 83, _tplCol: 85}
Uncaught EXCEPTION: Error in ./Spreadsheet class Spreadsheet - inline template:83:85
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at DebugAppView._View_Spreadsheet6.detectChangesInternal (Spreadsheet.template.js:1233:59)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/v4/beta/dist/vendor.bundle.js:47431:15)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/v4/beta/dist/vendor.bundle.js:47536:45)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectContentChildrenChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/v4/beta/dist/vendor.bundle.js:47449:20)
    at DebugAppView._View_Spreadsheet0.detectChangesInternal (Spreadsheet.template.js:557:8)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/v4/beta/dist/vendor.bundle.js:47431:15)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/v4/beta/dist/vendor.bundle.js:47536:45)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/v4/beta/dist/vendor.bundle.js:47457:20)
    at DebugAppView._View_Spreadsheet_Host0.detectChangesInternal (Spreadsheet_Host.template.js:36:8)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/v4/beta/dist/vendor.bundle.js:47431:15)
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]
```

Comment: Could you try using the ? operator.
"contact.phoine2?"

Comment: Yeah I had already done that, but we can't use expressions inside ngmodel

Comment: What if you just default the value when you get it.

Comment: Why can't you keep a property phone2 and left it blank?

Comment: Actually, this is coming from an API & there are lots of objects which could come if the user had filled them else not, so if I want to put any default value then I have to check which one is present and which is not which could be the hectic job.

Comment: @DheerajAgrawal It shouldn't throw when the prop is not present. What is the error msg?

Comment: Also the data is not in json format. Did you mean `results = [{name:...`?

Comment: @TamasHegedus I have updated my question with the error & yes I meant that json format ```[{....}, {....}]```

Comment: cannot read prop 0 of undefined - i think it has nothing to do with phone2.

Comment: @TamasHegedus Actually, the format is like this for phone {phone: [{number: 23433}, {number: 34333}]}

Comment: @DheerajAgrawal So you say literally none of the code you showed us belongs to the error you are searching the solution for. Please provide a way so we can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the good way is to prepare results array before rendering table in `ngOnInit()`.

Another way: in this code sample I use temp array to store user info and update the original array if user`s phone2 changes.

```
 @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
    <table><tr *ngFor="let contact of results; let i=index">
        <td><input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="contact.name"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="phone1" [(ngModel)]="contact.phone1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="phone2" [(ngModel)]="tempUsers[i].phone2" (ngModelChange)="updateResults(i)" ></td>
    </tr></table>`
    })
    export class AppComponent {

      public results = [
            {
                name: 'abc',
                phone1: '98888',
                phone2: '988883'
            },
            {
                name: 'xyz',
                phone1: '98888'
            }
        ];

        public tempUsers : [{
             name: string,
             phone1: string,
             phone2: string
        }] = [];

        ngOnInit() {
          let counter = 0;
          for(let ind in this.results) {

            this.tempUsers[ind] = {
              name: this.results[ind].name || '',
             phone1: this.results[ind].phone1 || '',
             phone2: this.results[ind].phone2 || ''
            };
          }
        }

        updateResults(index: number) {
          // copy tempUsers objects to results
          // use object`s index to copy only one object

        }
    }
```

Comment: its like adding default value and I have a big json in which almost this condition will be for every object so its kinda hectic job to define default value for everything.